# how to auto-play carousel using only css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a carousel built using CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/1y78zgvu/

Here is the CSS:

```
.landing-quotes {
  color: #284660;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 35px 0;
}
.landing-quotes .landing-quotes-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1110px;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-item {
  margin: 0 auto 80px auto;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 245px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}
.landing-quotes blockquote {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.landing-quotes blockquote p {
  font-family: "minion-pro-display", serif;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 3.07em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}
.landing-quotes blockquote p:before {
  content: open-quote;
}
.landing-quotes blockquote p:after {
  content: close-quote;
}
.landing-quotes blockquote footer cite {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: adobe-clean, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.23em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-indicators li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-indicators li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-bullet {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #284660;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.landing-quotes .carousel-bullet:hover {
  background-color: #284660;
}
.landing-quotes #carousel-1:checked ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
.landing-quotes #carousel-2:checked ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
.landing-quotes #carousel-3:checked ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  background-color: #284660;
}
```

How can I trigger the carousel to auto play using CSS only? If that is not possible, how can I use jquery to do so? I tried using CSS, but I can't figure out how to autoplay the carousel using only CSS. Only CSS would be ideal.

Here's my JQuery code so far:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        var carouselOpen$ = $( "input.carousel-open"),
            index = carouselOpen$.index(":checked"),
            len = carouselOpen$.length;

        console.debug(index);
        if (index >= 0) {
            carouselOpen$.eq(index).attr( "checked", false );

            if ((index + 1) >= len) {
                index = 0;
            } else {
                index += 1;
            }
            console.log(len);
            console.debug(index);
            carouselOpen$.eq(index).attr( "checked", true );
        }
    }, 5000);
```

It doesn't work for some reason.
Can I do this in CSS?

Comment: Try using `css` `animation`

Comment: how? can I do that using css animation?

Comment: See post; utilizes single `div` element, `data-*` attributes and `:after` pseudo element with `css` animation to render content in an infinite cycle.

Comment: can I do it using the structure I have above? don't want to change structure if I don't have to. thanks!

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. The most tedious portion would be coordinating the `animation-delay` or `%` at `keyframes` of each element, if use single `animation` declaration; or you could define an animation for each element. Would still need to check that overlap does not occur at rendering, unless that is expected. `css` at post attempts to demonstrate one possible approach of using single element to display different text in an infinite cycle. Multiple elements can be more challenging to coordinate, though you should be able to achieve requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using CSS, but I can't figure out how to autoplay the carousel
>   using only CSS. Only CSS would be ideal.
>
> Can I do this in CSS?

Yes, you can achieve a carousel or slideshow effect using only `css` `animation`; possibly including `css` `transition`, depending on expected rendering effect.

Approach at post uses single `<div>` element having `data-*` attributes set to store content to be displayed at `content` property of `:after` pseudo element of `div` element.

Multiple elements could also be combined into single animation cycle. Checking overlap at transitioning between states of single or multiple elements' animation effects without rendering portions of previous animation state would be most tedious portion of requirement.

```css
div {
  color: #fffff0;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  outline: 4px solid gold;
  text-shadow: -0.025em 0.15em #000;
}
div:after {
  white-space: pre;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid gold;
  font-size: 0px;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s;
  animation-name: cycle;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    background: sienna;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    opacity: .75;
    font-size: 0px;
    content: attr(data-a);
  }
  16% {
    border: 1px solid gold;
    background: purple;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 36px;
    content: attr(data-a);
  }
  33% {
    background: sienna;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    opacity: 0.75;
    font-size: 0px;
    content: attr(data-a);
  }
  34% {
    content: attr(data-b);
  }
  50% {
    background: purple;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 36px;
    content: attr(data-b);
  }
  66% {
    background: sienna;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    opacity: .75;
    font-size: 0px;
    content: attr(data-b);
  }
  67% {
    content: attr(data-c);
  }
  83% {
    background: purple;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 36px;
    content: attr(data-c);
  }
  100% {
    background: sienna;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    opacity: .75;
    font-size: 0px;
    content: attr(data-c);
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-a="'I am really impressed.'
Dala Et, Photographer" data-b="'I am really impressed.'
Era La, Actor" data-c="'I couldn't have asked.'
Bapo Bapo, Programmer"></div>
```